# jQuery jsonrpc 2.0 call via .ajax() gets correct response but does not work?

Tags: jquery, ajax

A jsonrpc 2.0 call via jquery to a Tornado web server gets a 
"200 OK" http response and my network sniffer shows the decoded
response as containing

**{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":null,"result":3500,"id":"jsonrpc"}**

i.e a valid jsonrpc 2.0 response. 3500 is also the correct result, 
the RPC was to a simple add function.

However firebug does not show response and .ajax **success** callback
is not triggered. The .ajax() **error** and **complete** callbacks are
triggered but give me no clue as to the problem. Here is the
index.html that triggers the ajax() call.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080', 
          data: JSON.stringify ({jsonrpc:'2.0',method:'add', params:[1400,2100],id:"jsonrpc"} ),  // id is needed !!
          type:"POST",
          dataType:"json",
          success: function (result) { 
                 alert("ok");
          },
          error: function (err,status,thrown) {
                 alert ("this syntax sucks!! " + " ERROR: " + err + " STATUS: " + status + " " + thrown );
          },
          complete: function (xhr,status) { 
                 alert('Complete=>  showing status as: '+ status); 
                 data = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);  
                 alert (data);
          } 
       });
    });
```

Comment: whats the status and err in error and complete?

Comment: Originally I was loading index.html (shown above) by using Firefox "File Open". Instead of doing that I had my Tornado web server deliver it when I browsed http://localhost:8080. This cleared up the problem completely. success now triggers and I get the correct remote procedure call result.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out that the problem was opening index.html using Firefox "File Open" instead of having my web server deliver index.html to me (by browsing http://localhost:8080)

Here is a complete working example of making a JSON RPC call and displaying the result using a simple alert. The RPC is a basic addition function.

To see it in action:

- Save index.html (2) and webserver.py (1). Edit webserver.py to
  reflect location of index.html
- Start webserver.py (chmod a+x  webserver.py. sudo ./webserver.py)
- Start Firefox and browse to localhost:8080. This will load index.html, 
   trigger the ajax() call and display the result using an alert.

(1) The web server is Tornado using the tornadorpc module and written in Python. Here it is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.6 

import tornado.httpserver import tornado.ioloop import tornado.web

from tornadorpc.json import JSONRPCHandler from tornadorpc import private, start_server


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,upath):
        self.write( open('/home/travis/EXPLORE/webApps/index.html').read() )            

class Tree(object):

    def power(self, base, power, modulo=None):
        return pow(base, power, modulo)

    def _private(self):
        # Won't be callable
        return False

class Handler(JSONRPCHandler):

    print ('In Handler()...') 
    tree = Tree()

    def add(self, x, y):
        print ('add()  method called...') 
        return x+y

    def ping(self, obj):
        return obj

# Order is important here.. first matched handler in array is used !! handlers = [
            ('/RPC2',Handler),
            (r"/(.*)", MainHandler),

            ]

start_server(handlers, port=8080)
```

(2) index.html uses jquery's ajax() method to make the JSONRPC call to the add remote procedure. Make sure where you save it to matches the path the webserver in (1) tries to read its contents from.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/RPC2', 

            data: JSON.stringify ({jsonrpc:'2.0',method:'add', params:[1400,2100],id:"jsonrpc"} ),  // id is needed !!

            type:"POST",

            dataType:"json",
            success:  function (data)       { alert("The result is : " + data.result);},
            error: function (err)  { alert ("Error");}

         });

      });


  </script>


</head>
<body>
  <h1> jQuery JSON RPC 2.0 demo </h1>

</body>
</html>
```