# Ajax to R via Rstudio

Tags: r, ajax

I started the server in Rstudio using servr::httd().

I hope to learn how to post data to R and back and I found the below.
([jQuery jsonrpc 2.0 call via .ajax() gets correct response but does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147211/jquery-jsonrpc-2-0-call-via-ajax-gets-correct-response-but-does-not-work))

I implemented the below codes on index.html and it looked fine.

However, I am unsure what I should code to implement the server side in Rstudio.

The server codes from above URL is for python, and I have been reading for a few days without finding the way how Rstudio should be done. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:4321/', 

            data: JSON.stringify ({jsonrpc:'2.0',method:'add', params:[1400,2100],id:"jsonrpc"} ),  

            type:"POST",

            dataType:"json",
            success:  function (data)       { alert("The result is : " + data.result);},
            error: function (err)  { alert ("Error");}

         });

      });


  </script>


</head>
<body>
  <h1> jQuery JSON RPC 2.0 demo </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, I see the connection between this and the previous question. You _really_ don't want to use the HTTP server that comes with the `servr` package for this. I know others will say differently, but you should use the `devd` server I mentioned in the other question as it's far more like a "real" web server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Yah it is so hard to make it work.